# Refs return as null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hammer.js, react-dom

I have an array of 'selected cards' stored in a 'selectedCards' state, which updates depending on whether the user has referenced the 'Card' ID or not (using a checkbox).

When the component mounts, a default array is mapped using the 'Card' component, and added into the stack. They are accessed using refs  and using a tinder-style interaction, users can throw out left or right by keyboard or dragging out of the stack.

When the component updates and adds new cards to the stack, the refs are returned as null. Why is this?

```
export default class Cards extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.config = {
      throwOutDistance: () => Math.max(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight),
      throwOutConfidence: () => 1,
      allowedDirections: [
        Direction.LEFT,
        Direction.RIGHT,
      ]
    };

    const fakeEvent = {
      target: {
        id: 'digiDesign',
      }
    };

    this.cardRefs = new Map();

    this.state = {
      selectedCategories: ['digiDesign', 'branding'],
      selectedCards: this.filterArray(fakeEvent),
      cardStack: cardData,
      currentCard: cardData.length - 1,
      cardIndex: 0,
      checked: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { selectedCards } = this.state;

    //Intiates key listener
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.onDirection);

    //Configures Swing.js
    this.stack = Stack(this.config);
    this.stack.on("dragstart", () => this.setState({ dragging: true }));
    this.stack.on("dragend", () => this.setState({ dragging: false }));
    this.stack.on("throwout", this.onThrowOut.bind(this));

    //Config stack of cards
    this.createStack();

    //Logs initial cards
    console.log(selectedCards, 'selected cards')
  }

  handleChange(e){
    const { selectedCards } = this.state;

    if (e.target.checked){
      for (let i = 0; i < this.filterArray(e).length; i++){
        selectedCards.push(this.filterArray(e)[i])
      }
    } if (!e.target.checked){
      this.removeArray(e);
    }

    this.setState({
      selectedCards
    })

    console.log(selectedCards)
  }

  createStack(){
    const { selectedCards } = this.state;
    this.cardRefs.forEach((ref) => {
      const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref);
      this.stack.createCard(el);
  });

    this.setState({
      currentCard: selectedCards.length - 1
    })
  }

  destroyStack(){
    this.cardRefs.forEach((ref) => {
      const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref);
      const card = this.stack.getCard(el);
      card.destroy();
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.destroyStack()
  }

  //Controls keycodes
  onDirection = e => {
    if(e.keyCode === 37){
      this.throwoutLeft();
    } if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      this.throwoutRight();
    }
  }

  //Controls throwout right with key
  throwoutRight(){
    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
      this.cardRefs.get(this.state.currentCard)
    );
    const card = this.stack.getCard(el);
    card.throwOut(1000, 0);
  }

  //Controls throwout left with key
  throwoutLeft(){
    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
      this.cardRefs.get(this.state.currentCard)
    );
    const card = this.stack.getCard(el);
    card.throwOut(-1000, 0);
  }

  //Controls swipe/grab
  onThrowOut() {
    const activeCard = this.state.currentCard

    if (activeCard > 0){
      this.setState({
        currentCard: activeCard - 1
      })
    }

    if (activeCard === 0){
      this.setState({
        currentCard: activeCard - 1
      })
      this.resetDeck();
    }
  }

  //Resets the deck on finish
  resetDeck() {
    const { selectedCards } = this.state


    this.setState({
      currentCard:selectedCards.length - 1,
      resetting: true
    });

    this.createStack()

    this.setState({
      resetting: false,
    });
  }

 //Controls checkboxes
  filterArray(e){
    let filteredArray = cardData.filter(function(x){
      return x.id === e.target.id
    });
    return filteredArray
  }

  removeArray(e){
    const{ selectedCards } = this.state;
    for (let i = selectedCards.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
      if(selectedCards[i].id === e.target.id){
        selectedCards.splice(i, 1)
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedCards } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className='container'>
      <Viewport>
        <CardStack className='stack'>
          {selectedCards.map((card, i) => {
            return (
              <Card
                selectedCategories={this.state.selectedCategories}
                key={card.advice}
                ref={c => this.cardRefs.set(i, c)}
                advice={card.advice}
                id={card.id}
                tag={card.tag}
                isSelected={this.state.selectedCategories.indexOf(card.id) > -1}
                active={i === this.state.currentCard}
                next={i === this.state.currentCard - 1}
                previous={i > this.state.currentCard}
                dragging={
                  (i === this.state.currentCard && this.state.dragging) ||
                  this.state.resetting
                }
              />
            )
          })}
        </CardStack>
        <FilterContainer>
          {
            filterData.map((item, i) => {

              const active = i === 0;
              return (
                <Filters
                  ref='input'
                  key={item.id}
                  id={item.id}
                  label={item.label}
                  onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                  active={active}
                />
              )
            })
          }
        </FilterContainer>
      </Viewport>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The expected result is for the new cards to receive the 'throwIn' function, but seeing as though the new refs are returning as null, this cannot be achieved.

Comment: Why not just use a plain object for `carRefs` and then `ref={c => this.cardRefs[card.id] = c}`. You can easily `Object.values(this.cardRefs)` if you need to loop through these refs in future. Also storing by index seems a bit prone to errors

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Map, an Array-iterable to store your refs. You'll have to transform the Map back into an array before you can use methods like forEach.

```
  createStack(){
    const { selectedCards } = this.state;
    let allRefs = Array.from(this.refs.values())
    allRefs.forEach((ref) => {
      const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref);
      this.stack.createCard(el);
    });

    this.setState({
      currentCard: selectedCards.length - 1
    })
  }

  destroyStack(){
    let allRefs = Array.from(this.refs.values())
    allRefs.forEach((ref) => {
      const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref);
      const card = this.stack.getCard(el);
      card.destroy();
    });
  }
```

Hope that helps!